# Redis timeout exception in spring boot app using docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have Redis and some other services running on docker and connecting my application locally.

Some times I see the redis timeout error in the application. Not sure where and how to fix it.

As a workaround I restart my docker and application which solves the problem.

Docker compose config

redis:
image: redis:3.0.7
ports:
  - "6379:6379"

StackTrace

```
    org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisExceptionConverter.convert(JedisExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisExceptionConverter.convert(JedisExceptionConverter.java:36)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:37)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:37)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.convertJedisAccessException(JedisConnection.java:210)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.hGetAll(JedisConnection.java:2799)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations$13.doInRedis(DefaultHashOperations.java:223)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations$13.doInRedis(DefaultHashOperations.java:220)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:191)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:153)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.execute(AbstractOperations.java:86)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations.entries(DefaultHashOperations.java:220)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultBoundHashOperations.entries(DefaultBoundHashOperations.java:101)
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.getSession(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:233)
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.getSession(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:220)
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.getSession(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:141)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes.updateAccessedSessionAttributes(ServletRequestAttributes.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.AbstractRequestAttributes.requestCompleted(AbstractRequestAttributes.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:41002)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve.invoke(LogbackValve.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:201)
    at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.readByte(RedisInputStream.java:40)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:141)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:205)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:297)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getBinaryMultiBulkReply(Connection.java:233)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.hgetAll(BinaryJedis.java:930)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.hGetAll(JedisConnection.java:2797)
    ... 54 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(SocketInputStream.java)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:127)
    at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:195)
```

Comment: How about increasing the timeout? Maybe posting docker or redis configuration could also help.

Comment: It was already added in the description. Trying out the timeout to see if it works.

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem ?